# udev rules not executing script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, udev, bluetooth

first up some context. I use Ubuntu 18.04. I use a bluetooth peripheral mouse/keyboard, which, when connected, should execute a script to automatically remap button bindings.

I used `udevadm monitor --environment` to locate the event that occurs when connecting the device and used `udevadm info -a <device path>` to find attributes I could create rules for. Here is the output:

```
    KERNEL=="input73"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{name}=="BT Mouse"
    ATTR{phys}=="e8:9c:67:ea:9c:36"
    ATTR{properties}=="0"
    ATTR{uniq}=="01:ac:78:f6:89:af"
```

So I created a rule `/etc/udev/99-btmouse.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTR{name}=="BT Mouse", RUN="/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/xsessionrc.sh"
```

And I checked using

```
udevadm test <device path>
```

to make sure the rule is formatted correctly. Output:

```
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-vrpark.rules
rules contain 786432 bytes tokens (65536 * 12 bytes), 50615 bytes strings
38504 strings (296742 bytes), 32602 de-duplicated (252030 bytes), 5903 trie nodes used
...
RUN '/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/xsessionrc.sh' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-vrpark.rules:1
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=<device path>
EV=17
ID_BUS=bluetooth
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_5_1_0
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_5_1_0
KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
MODALIAS=input:b0005v05ACp3232e0001-e0,1,2,4,k110,111,112,113,114,r0,1,8,B,am4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="BT Mouse"
PHYS="e8:9c:67:ea:9c:36"
PRODUCT=5/5ac/3232/1
PROP=0
REL=903
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:seat:
UNIQ="01:ac:78:f6:89:af"
USEC_INITIALIZED=8737148529
run: '/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/xsessionrc.sh'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

This looks to me like the rule should be just fine, however the script never executes. This is what xsessionrc.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Map buttons
konsole --noclose -e xinput set-button-map "BT Mouse" 11 12 13 14
```

The script on it's own works fine for me. Could somebody point me in the right direction as to how to get my rule to execute a script?

Comment: Is `$DISPLAY` set in `xsessionrc.sh` when it's run by udev?

Comment: I am not quite familiar with linux so I appologize in advance. How do I check that and how does that affect the script? I ran echo $DISPLAY from within the xsessionrc.sh script and it put out :0.

Comment: Does it output `:0` when you run the script in the terminal? It looks good. Now see what's the value of `DISPLAY` when it's run by `udev`. You won't be able to see it on the screen so redirect it to the file: `echo $DISPLAY > /tmp/DISPLAY`. BTW, you don't need to start `konsole` - `xinput set-button-map "BT Mouse" 11 12 13 14` should be enough.

Comment: Yes, it puts out `:0` when run through the terminal. When run through `udev` it does create the file put the output is empty.

Comment: It mean that `DISPLAY` is not set. Try `DISPLAY=:0 xinput et-button-map "BT Mouse" 11 12 13 14`.

Comment: The `/tmp/DISPLAY` file now says `:0`, however the `xinput set-button-map "BT Mouse" 11 12 13 14` command is still not executing as far as I can tell.